# Create complex JSON objects

Tags: api, mobile, azure, service

Hi I have a question to the azure mobile Service custom API script.

I have a custom script to create a JSON Response.
First step was to get flat objects.

Thsi is my code:

```
var sql = "SELECT [Project].[id] AS [ID]," +
    "[Project].[Name] AS [Name]," +
    "FROM [Project]";

request.service.mssql.query(sql, [], {
    success: function(results) {

        if (results.length === 0) {
            response.json(statusCodes.OK, results);
            return;
        }

        var resultSet = [];

        results.forEach(function(poi) {
            resultSet.push(
                {
                    ID: poi.ID,
                    Name: poi.Name,
                    RelatedObjects:
                    {
                        [
                           **???**
                        ]                        
                    },
                });
        })

         response.json(statusCodes.OK, resultSet);
    }
});
```

This works very well. Now I want to extend my result objects by some sub objects from a releated table. But not simple singel sub properties (this is easy via join), I want to add collections of sub properties selected from another table.
But I don't know how to get the second query into my code? :(

I think it has to be on "**???**" marked position.

I want to use this JSON self creating code because my result sets are much more complex as the example shows.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solve it with this messi code...
I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this but I don't found it yet.

```
var sql = "SELECT [Project].[ID]" +
    ",[Project].[Name]" +
    "FROM [Project]";

var sql2 = "SELECT [ID]" +
    ",[UniqueSN]" +
    ",[Name]" +
    "FROM [DataLogger]" +
    "WHERE [DataLogger].[ProjectID] = ?";

request.service.mssql.query(sql, [id], {

    success: function(results) {

        var resultSet = [];

        results.forEach(function(poi) {

            var loggerResultSet = [];

            request.service.mssql.query(sql2, [poi.ID], {
                success: function(results2) {

                    results2.forEach(function(logger) {
                        loggerResultSet.push(
                            {
                                ID: logger.ID,
                                Name: logger.Name,
                                UniqueSN: logger.UniqueSN,
                            });
                    })

                    resultSet.push(
                        {
                            ID: poi.ID,
                            Name: poi.Name,
                            Logger: loggerResultSet,
                        });

                    response.json(statusCodes.OK, resultSet);


                    console.log(JSON.stringify(resultSet));
                }
            });
        })
     }
});
```